# Cakephp 2 ACL controlled plugin

Tags: php, authentication, plugins, acl, cakephp-2.4

I am developing a plugin por CakePHP 2.

I am intereseted in creating an authentication and ACL layer, but I dont know how to create the db ACL tables for my plugin. I was reading the documentation but doesn.t mention anything for plugins.

Is it possible, or I have to develope an application that uses my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

use basic ACL cakephp plugin and try finding aro acos extension for it..

Answer (score 0):

Try to study Croogo, Croogo is a CMS pluginized with ACL plugin and Users Plugin and a lot of things Pluginized.
After a while You can understand the way to do what you need. Check 1.5.4 release, not < and not >, because before Croogo was not pluginized and in future there will be a change.. ;-)